# Teamcity WebSocket not working

Tags: websocket, teamcity

I've set up a TeamCity instance on an AWS E2 Windows Server 2012 Machine. It is listening on port 80 which works fine. It is running on the webserver that it ships with it.

However the websocket support is not working. When logging in it says

> Some users cannot use optimized web UI updates via WebSocket protocol.

This error only appears when logging in from remote. When connected via RDP on localhost everything works fine. Therefore I assume that this is because of a blocked port.

This are all inbound rules I configured:
[image]

I already did some research but wasn't able to find the port that has to be opened that WebSockets are working. Is there a general rule which port is used for this or is this specified in a config?

**Edit:**

The Network analysis of Chrome gives me a 501 for the websocket request when loading the start page of TeamCity.

```
Request URL: ******
Request Method:GET
Status Code:501 Not Implemented
Response Headers
view source
Cache-Control:no-store
Connection:keep-alive
Date:Sat, 09 Sep 2017 20:25:41 GMT
Set-Cookie: *****
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Atmosphere-error:Websocket protocol not supported
X-Atmosphere-first-request:true
X-Atmosphere-tracking-id:53449aaa-16c6-43fd-a2bb-ae0da8a6fee1
Request Headers
view source
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:Upgrade
Cookie: ******
DNT:1
Host: ******
Origin: ******
Pragma:no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions:permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
Sec-WebSocket-Key: ******
Sec-WebSocket-Version:13
Upgrade:websocket
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36
Query String Parameters
view source
view URL encoded
X-Atmosphere-tracking-id:0
X-Atmosphere-Framework:2.2.13-javascript
X-Atmosphere-Transport:websocket
X-Atmosphere-TrackMessageSize:true
browserLocationHost: ******
```

Answer (score 0):

After modifying the server configuration and looking through the logs I noticed that the handshake for the web socket failed. The headers were incomplete.

In the end this was caused by my VPN that blocked the web socket handshake.